# Define a unique integer for every node

Tags: c++

I am making a c++ application to store data about products, each product has a unique integer ID, is there a way to do that??

I have made this class Node for products, but I don't know how to make the ID unique:

```
class Node{
public:
    int ID;
    int cost;
    int quantity;
    string Name;

Node(){ID=0; cost=0;quantity=0; Name="";}

};
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is asking. Are you asking for ways to generate unique ids? If so, is this a single machine application or do you need to generate integers that are unique across multiple machines? Do the IDs need to be integers at all? What other properties do the IDs need to support? Are you asking if there is a way to tell C++ (via the type system) that the ID needs to be unique for each object?

Answer (score 1):

Use a static variable:

```
Node(){
static int id = 0;
ID=id; 
id++;
cost=0;
quantity=0; 
Name="";}
```

Also, I would use `unsigned int` instead of `int`.

Another idea:
In order to make the code persistent and thread-safe, I would write the last ID on a file every time a node is created. The file would be read at first when program starts, in the constructor of another `singleton` class. Finally, this class would protect the method that generates IDs with a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  One way would simply be to have a global variable in the header file in which your class resides, which is used to define the ID, and is incremented after assigning each ID.  However, many people try to use global variables as little as possible - it's too easy for them to be modified when you aren't expecting it.

A better way might be to create a different class (let's call it `NodeManager`), which has a member variable which keeps track of the current ID, increments the member variable every time a new ID is requested, and must be passed into the constructor of `Node`.

A slightly more concise way which would also avoid a global variable would be to use a static variable.  Static variables are the same across all instances of the class, so you could use this to keep track of the current ID.